# Java Sliding Window over Socketinputstreams

Tags: java, stream, streaming, inputstream, sliding-window

I have an android app which streams Sensordata( as a String) over TCP to a java Server application.Relevant code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
while (running && in != null) {
    String message = in.readLine();
    if (message != null) {
       this.messageReceived(message);
    }
}
```

At the moment i write the message in a text file in the messageReceived method and it works fine. When i send a "stop" message from my android app, the text file  will be saved and the file is used for automatic processing. The problem is, i don´t want to send a "stop" flag from my App to start the processing rather i want to buffer the messages and use something like a sliding window which saves some data to a txtfile and process it automatically.
For example,When i receive following lines:

1. "2.0, 1.0, 3.2"
2. "2.4, 2.1, 4.2"
3. "1.0, 5.0, 8.2"
4. "3.4, 3.1, 2.2"
5. "1.4, 5.1, 5.2"
6. "6.0, 8.0, 6.2"
7. "9.4, 9.1, 7.2"

The first txt file should contain lines 1-3 the second one 3-5, the third one 5-7 and so one (in reality the window size should be much bigger and the overlapping to). I have no idea how to implement that after days of research.

Comment: Which version of Java is this? I'm guessing 7 since you mentioned android

Comment: Also show what you have attempted to do

Comment: @smac89 No I use java 8, the Client is an Android App, but that problem is server related and written in eclipse with java 8. As i said by now i only save the received lines of data in one file after a signal from the android app. My research on sliding windows only gives solution on fixed data inputs, maybe an array of numbers and how to implement a sliding window for this. But as i get data continously from my android app, i have to buffer it somehow... I found nothing comparable for that problem.

Comment: From the way you have this set up, how would you know when the reader has finished reading? Usually people know this when the reader returns null, but in your case, you are ignoring the null.

Comment: yeah, thats the problem. The reader wont be null until the user close the App on his phone. As long as the app runs, Sensor data will be streamed to the server continously. I have to buffer that data somehow, and when enough data is there i create a txt file from the Data in the buffer, pop the first data, and fill the buffer with newer data. So basically a sliding window over a possibly infinite data stream... May be i can store data in an array of fixed length, when its full i create the txt file with data in it and while i process the txt file i buffer the incoming data in a queue

Comment: And when the processing is done i pull data from the queue and put it in the array.. Don´t know if that makes sense, but discussing about a problem often helps

Comment: Yea that's what I'm thinking as well, some sort of iterator which yields chunks of the data at a time and "slides" (pops) a given amount, then does the same again

Comment: Thanks man for the discussion, i will try that.

Comment: Haven't fully tested this idea, but I cooked up something: https://gist.github.com/smac89/5bdafdc2a10cf942afe003061bdaaba2. The idea is to wrap your buffferedreader with the supplier and then have a predicate for when you want the reading to stop. This will create a `java.util.stream.Stream` object which will "slide" over the data producing a list of items which were read

Comment: Thank you ! That looks great. But i actually don´t figured out, how to wrap my bufferedreader. Works amazing with the IntStream. Can you help me, how to substitute the IntStream with the bufferedReader? So i have the same thing with Strings instread of ints.